# Can we remove 'Open Calendar' link from Account/Contact/Lead list views? if yes, how?

Tags: account, leads, contact, configuration, list-view

I want to remove open Calendar link available on Account/Contact/lead list views: [image: 'openCalendar' link on list view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 'OpenCalendar' link can be removed via user Interface.
From Setup > Build > Customize > User Interface: 
Disable/deselect--> 
'Enable Click-and-Create Events on Calendar Views' and
'Enable Drag-and-Drop Scheduling on List Views

'[image: Deselect below checkboxes]